# Como utilizar JProgressBar enquanto método(retorna valor) executa leitura de arquivos XML?

Tags: java

Tenho um pouco de conhecimento em Java e já pesquisei a fundo na internet sobre como utilizar um JProgressBar enquanto executo um método, porem não consegui nenhum exemplo que funcione conforme minha necessidade ja que meu método retorna um valor.
Logica = Tenho uma Classe (CarregarXmls), que possui um método (xmlAut), este método realiza a leitura de n arquivos Xml e adiciona cada um deles em uma lista que seguidamente a lista e adicionada a um tableModel (modeloTabelaAut) . Apos ler o ultimo arquivo o método retorna um TableModel que sera utilizado para preencher uma tabela.
O que preciso = Enquanto o método realizar a leitura gostaria ou de um GIF de aguarde ou um JProgressBar para que a tela não fique estática, dando a impressão que esta travado.
Se alguém puder me fornecer informações de como fazer esta missão seria de enorme ajuda.

Segue código da minha classe CarregarXMLs com o metodo xmlAut:

```
package br.com.leitorXml;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;

import br.com.Dados.Dados;
import br.com.UTIL.VerificaString;
import br.com.UTIL.XmlUtil;

public class CarregarXmls extends JFrame
{

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1295991874261633841L;
    File[]  arquivosCanc = null;
    String diretorioBackup = null, conteudoSelecionado = null;


    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    public ModeloDadosAut xmlAut ()
    {

        JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
        List ListaDadosAut = null;

        final ModeloDadosAut modeloTabelaAut = new ModeloDadosAut();

        // DEVERA ABRIR PASTAS E VARIOS ARQUIVOS
        fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES); // ARQUIVOS E DIRETORIOS
        //      fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);  // SOMENTE ARQUIVOS

        // TITULO JANELA
        fc.setDialogTitle("Selecione os arquivos ou uma pasta"); 

        // CRIANDO FILTRO XML
        FileNameExtensionFilter filtroXml = new FileNameExtensionFilter 
                ("xml files (*.xml)", "xml");
        fc.setFileFilter(filtroXml); // FILTRANDO SOMENTE ARQUIVOS XMLS
        fc.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
        File diretorio;

        // DEFININDO DIRETORIO INCIAL
        //SE A VARIAVEL DIRETORIOBACKUP ESTIVER NULL COLOQUE DIRETORIO INCIAL C:\
        if(diretorioBackup != null)
        {
            diretorio = new File(""+diretorioBackup+"");
        }
        // SE NAO ESTIVER NULL COLOQUE ULTIMO CAMINHO UTILIZADO
        else
            diretorio = new File("c:\\");

        fc.setCurrentDirectory(diretorio);

        //  CRIA POP UP
        int res = fc.showOpenDialog(new JFrame());


        //APOS SELECIONAR O BOTAO ABRIR 
        if(res == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
        {           

            System.out.println("Verificar o que foi selecionado (pasta ou arquivo) = " +fc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
            // ATRIBUINDO NA VARIAVEL conteudoSelecionado PARA QUE SEJA UTILIZADO NO METODO ModeloDadosCanc
            conteudoSelecionado = fc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();



            // SE FOR SELECIONADO UM OU MAIS ARQUIVOS xml RETORNA FALSE
            if(VerificaString.VerificaConteudoSelecionado(fc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath()) == false)
            {

                File[] arquivos = fc.getSelectedFiles();  
                arquivosCanc = fc.getSelectedFiles(); // ATRIBUINDO PARA DEPOIS SER UTILIZADO NO METODO XMLCANC
                qtdArquivos = arquivos.length;                      

                //                          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Voce escolheu os arquivos: \n" + arquivos.getName());
                System.out.println("Voce selecionou os arquivos listados abaixo:");         



                for(int i = 0; i < arquivos.length; i++)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        System.out.println("\nDentro do For (autorizados) = "+arquivos[i].toString());
                        diretorioBackup = arquivos[i].toString();
                        System.out.println("\nDentro do For (autorizados) diretorioBackup "+ diretorioBackup); 
                        ListaDadosAut = XmlUtil.lerArquivoAutorizadoReceita(arquivos[i].getPath(), arquivos[i].getName());

                        modeloTabelaAut.carregarDados(ListaDadosAut);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e1) 
                    {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }// FIM DO FOR
                return modeloTabelaAut;
            }// FIM DO IF SELECIONANDO ARQUIVOS XML

        }
        else
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Voce nao selecionou nenhum arquivo.");         
            return null;
        }
        return modeloTabelaAut;

        }// Fim do METODO xmlAut
```

Comment: Sabe utilizar Threads?

Comment: Andei pesquisando alguns exemplos com Threads, porem vi que quando executo o método em uma Thread não e possível retornar um valor. E no meu caso preciso que retorne um TableModel.

Comment: http://www.guj.com.br/t/jprogressbar-em-thread/225147/2

Comment: Tente utilizar uma variável global.

Comment: Está usando netbeans ?

Comment: Aqui tem outro exemplo: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19312658/how-to-set-the-jprogressbar-working-according-to-the-time-taken-for-a-task-in-ja

Comment: Dê uma olhada em [`Future<V>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html). A ideia é retornar não um `ModeloDadosAut` mas um `Future<ModeloDadosAut>`, e fazer com que o thread responsável pela execução (por exemplo um [`SwingWorker`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html), que implementa `Future`) coloque um valor final nesse `Future` quando estiver pronto. Pois retornar diretamente é inviável - principalmente se o método for chamado no *event dispatcher thread* (já que assim a tela travaria toda até o fim da execução).

Comment: @mgibsonbr nao consegui entender muito bem como implementar este future<v>. Teria algum exemplo pratico para me mostrar?

Comment: @Techies Estou utilizando Eclipse, os exemplos que voce me enviou sao exemplos que eu ja tinha tentado adaptar ao meu uso, mas nao consegui.

Comment: @DouglasRibeiro Sim, eu posso tentar, me dá só um tempinho. Também gostaria de saber o seguinte: quem chama o `xmlAut`? O valor de retorno desse método pode ser mudado? E o código que chama `xmlAut` está rodando a partir de que *thread*? (por exemplo, se esse código executa após o clique de um botão, ele está no *event dispatcher thread*, a menos que você tenha colocado-o para executar em um thread diferente) Pergunto porque se não tiver problema *bloquear* esse thread, a solução fica mais simples (mas se for o EDT então não pode bloquear senão trava a tela).

Comment: Sem problemas@mgibsonbr ,Nao posso mudar o valor de retorno do metodo, o codigo que chama xmlAut nao esta rodando em uma thread.Ele e executado apos um clique. Segue código da minha classe de visão que chama o método xmlAut da classe CarregarXML. E chamado dentro de um Jbutton: btnCarregar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) { tabelaAut.setModel(xml.xmlAut()); } });// FIM DO BTNCARREGAR –

Comment: Pensei aqui, e não encontrei um meio de fazer o que você quer. Pois o código do `ActionListener` vai executar no EDT, ele precisa completar antes de liberar o EDT, e você não pode bloquear o EDT sem travar a tela. O que você pode fazer é criar e retornar o seu `ModeloDadosAut`, vazio, então populá-lo em um outro thread e no final chamar `modeloTabelaAut.fireTableStructureChanged()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como seu código chamador está no *Event Dispatcher Thread* - e ele precisa completar antes de liberar o EDT para continuar gerenciando a interface gráfica do Swing - então só lhe restam duas opções:

1. Modificar o código chamador para não fazer essa atualização no EDT e sim em uma outra thread;
2. Retornar seu modelo de tabela vazio, populá-lo em outro thread, e então notificar a tabela que esse modelo mudou.

Acho que essa segunda opção é mais simples, se não trouxer nenhum efeito indesejado em se usar um modelo de tabela vazio enquanto os dados são preenchidos. A única alteração que você teria de fazer no seu código é a seguinte:

```
// Precisa ser final, pra poder ser acessada dentro do thread
final File[] arquivos = fc.getSelectedFiles();  

arquivosCanc = fc.getSelectedFiles(); // ATRIBUINDO PARA DEPOIS SER UTILIZADO NO METODO XMLCANC
qtdArquivos = arquivos.length;         
System.out.println("Voce selecionou os arquivos listados abaixo:");         

new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

        for(int i = 0; i < arquivos.length; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                System.out.println("\nDentro do For (autorizados) = "+arquivos[i].toString());
                diretorioBackup = arquivos[i].toString();
                System.out.println("\nDentro do For (autorizados) diretorioBackup "+ diretorioBackup); 
                ListaDadosAut = XmlUtil.lerArquivoAutorizadoReceita(arquivos[i].getPath(), arquivos[i].getName());

                modeloTabelaAut.carregarDados(ListaDadosAut);
            }
            catch (Exception e1) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }// FIM DO FOR

        modeloTabelaAut.fireTableDataChanged(); // Notifica a tabela que os dados mudaram

    } // Fim do run
}).start();

return modeloTabelaAut; // A tabela está sendo retornada vazia
```

(Nota: se a *estrutura* da tabela também mudou dentro do loop - por exemplo colunas foram acrescentadas ou alteradas - use `fireTableStructureChanged` em vez de `fireTableDataChanged`)

Aí então você pode atualizar livremente um `JProgressBar` dentro do loop que está no thread. Por exemplo, assumindo que você criou uma barra de progresso chamada `barraProgresso`, você pode atualizá-la da seguinte forma:

```
barraProgresso.setValue(0);
barraProgresso.setMaximum(arquivos.length + 1);

new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

        for(int i = 0; i < arquivos.length; i++)
        {
            barraProgresso.setValue(i+1);
            ...
        }
        barraProgresso.setValue(arquivos.length + 1);
```

Comment: realmente a tela fica totalmente travada só nao sabia que era devido o EDT ainda nao ter sido finalizado, esta segunda opção deu certo e através desse forum consegui aprender muito sobre Threads. Muito obrigado mesmo!